# show that: $ \alpha (X,Y)=0\Rightarrow X=Y~~a.s $

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(S, d)$ - a metric space and $X, Y : \Omega \to S$ - random variables with values in $S$. we pose The quantity :
$$
\alpha(X, Y ) = \inf \big\{ε > 0 ~:~ \mathbb{P}\big(\{\omega\in\Omega~:~ d(X(\omega),Y(\omega)) > \epsilon \}\big) \leq \epsilon\big\}
$$
I want to Show that : $\alpha$ is a metric on the set $L^{0}(\Omega, S)$ of classes of equivalences of such random variables, where two r.v.s are equivalent if they are equal a.s.

**but I have a problem to show that:**

$$
\alpha (X,Y)=0\Rightarrow X=Y~~a.s
$$

An idea please.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha(X, Y)=0$, then there exists $\varepsilon_n \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$ such that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>\varepsilon_n \right) \leq \varepsilon_n $$
by definition of $\alpha$. Now you can apply Borel-Cantelli lemma to show that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( d(X(\omega), Y(\omega)) > \varepsilon_n \text{ i.o.}\right)=0. $$
But it's cleat that $d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>\varepsilon_n$ i.o. happens iff $d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>0$.This shows that $\mathbb{P}(d(X(\omega), Y(\omega)>0)=0$.

Comment: I do not know this lemma. can you detail me please

Comment: what do you mean by : "i.o"

Comment: I read on Wiki this "Borel-Cantelli lemma" and also "infinitely often" but I have a problem of showing :$$ d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>0\Rightarrow d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>\varepsilon_n~~ i.o.$$

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't at home. As you probably already saw, the "i.o." concept means that $d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))>\varepsilon_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is a basic but important tool in probability and measure theory.

Comment: For your other question, lets call $d(X(\omega), Y(\omega))=\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\varepsilon > 2^{-n}$ for every $n \geq N$ (that is just because $2^{-n} \to 0$). But now $\varepsilon > \varepsilon_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much